# I can't change my linux permissions. I want to create an .env file

Tags: linux, laravel, amazon-ec2

I'm having trouble deploying my Laravel project to EC2.
I ran cp .env.example .env because I wanted to create an .env file in my Laravel project, but cp: I can't create the regular file `.env': Permission denied

The laravel project is in / var / www / html / laravel-project

The result of the ls -l command

```
/ var / www / html 
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096  5月 31 12:44　laravel-project
```

```
/ var / www / html /laravel-project

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     42  5月 31 12:44 Procfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2140  5月 31 12:44 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root    147  5月 31 12:44 app
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1686  5月 31 12:44 artisan
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     34  5月 31 12:44 bootstrap
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1756  5月 31 12:44 composer.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 290632  5月 31 12:44 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    282  5月 31 12:44 config
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     72  5月 31 12:44 database
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1004  5月 31 12:44 package.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1140  5月 31 12:44 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     95  5月 31 12:44 public
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root     53  5月 31 12:44 resources
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     75  5月 31 12:44 routes
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    563  5月 31 12:44 server.php
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     46  5月 31 12:44 storage
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     83  5月 31 12:44 tests
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    538  5月 31 12:44 webpack.mix.js
```

Comment: You should talk to the administrator of the server about why you don't have permissions to create the file.

Answer (score 0):

You should have root permission to give another user permission to create a file.

```
drwxr-xr-x
      ^^
```

It shows you only have execution and read permission right now on the project directory.

If you want to give every user same permission, then permission command will be something like this

```
sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html/laravel-project
```